# Install peer dependencies as dev dependencies when developing a package?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

My package `foo` depends on a module `bar` as a peer dependency. So aribtrary parent `buzz` would install `foo`, and need to install `bar` for it and `foo` to share it. I'm now developing `foo` and adding `bar` as a peer dependency with yarn doesn't install it (weird given that this is the package itself).

Do I need to add `bar` as a dev dependency too to be able to actually use it while developing `foo`? Or are there specific commands to install peer dependencies in the project without having to repeat each peer dependency in the dev dependency list?

Looking through Yarn's documentation, I can't find a clear answer.

I'm also tagging `npm` incase there's a general convention that an npm user could share.

Comment: if you use yarn, looks like it is the way you have to. See this [topic](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1503) about to ask if yarn can automatically install peerDeps in dev mode, and the topic is closed at the end -_-! On the other side, npm@v7 now support it.